# How to parse JSON string for List of List of anonymous object which contains List of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, json.net

I've been trying to deserialize the following JSON string into a model using Newtonsoft's Json library, but failing to do so. The json string is as follows:-

```json
[
    [
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "d": "Dec 2019 Final",
                    "e": "Released 5 Mar 2020"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "d": "Some String",
                    "e": "Some Other string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I tried doing so by creating its model using Visual Studio internal tool for json to C# (paste special). Also tried creating the models using QuickTypes.io, but so far nothing worked.

The best I can do is parse the api response as `List<List<object>>` and then manually get the values by iterating its keys & values, which is something I totally want to avoid.
Is there a better way to handle this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a base model and parse your json:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public List<EventModel> Events { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "d")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "e")]
        public string Event { get; set; }
    }
```

And for deserialize json to model use this:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<BaseClass>>>("your json");
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your question correctly.If you want to stick to Anonymous types, you could make use of `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType` for the purpose.

```
var innerAnonymousType = new {d=string.Empty,e=string.Empty};
var innerAnnonymousTypeList = CreateList(innerAnonymousType);
var outerAnonymousType = CreateList(new {events = innerAnnonymousTypeList});
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, CreateList(outerAnonymousType));
```

Where CreateList is defined as

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] elements)
{
     return new List<T>(elements);
}
```

[Using JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

Output Sample

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. This surely does the job, but the issue remains with non static type objects, that its hard to access the objects value. Rather then anonymous object, a concrete implementations is always preferred.

Comment: @AbhiAbzs As I mentioned, Title of Question was misleading, which is why i struck with AnonymousTypes. But glad that you found your solution